# Google Map API & JavaScript Issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js, google-maps

I am using Google Maps API and custom JScript to be able to calculate snow loads in Tahoe Basin.

This all works as expected except for one county...El Dorado, which does not work, and I have not been able to isolate the issue.

If you load the snippet (best in full screen) you can see that it works for all counties around the lake except for El Dorado County.

**NOTE:** To reproduce the error: Load snippet in full screen and Goto South Lake Tahoe and click on that town that is El Dorado County and it errors.

```js
var points = {
  westPlacer: [
    {
      lat: 39.373490,
      long: -120.235205
    }, {
      lat: 39.359037,
      long: -120.235319
    }, {
      lat: 39.343940,
      long: -120.235506
    }, {
      lat: 39.329288,
      long: -120.235731
    }, {
      lat: 39.314982,
      long: -120.236251
    }, {
      lat: 39.300705,
      long: -120.236422
    }, {
      lat: 39.285794,
      long: -120.236672
    }, {
      lat: 39.271297,
      long: -120.236402
    }, {
      lat: 39.256740,
      long: -120.236290
    }, {
      lat: 39.242320,
      long: -120.236151
    }, {
      lat: 39.227314,
      long: -120.236011
    }, {
      lat: 39.213102,
      long: -120.235911
    }, {
      lat: 39.198786,
      long: -120.235766
    }, {
      lat: 39.184576,
      long: -120.236484
    }, {
      lat: 39.184575,
      long: -120.236484
    }, {
      lat: 39.184119,
      long: -120.228208
    }, {
      lat: 39.170143,
      long: -120.228036
    }, {
      lat: 39.154701,
      long: -120.190700
    }, {
      lat: 39.154700,
      long: -120.190700
    }, {
      lat: 39.140015,
      long: -120.190456
    }, {
      lat: 39.125517,
      long: -120.190547
    }, {
      lat: 39.111406,
      long: -120.190561
    }, {
      lat: 39.096556,
      long: -120.190558
    }, {
      lat: 39.082067,
      long: -120.190534
    }, {
      lat: 39.077698,
      long: -120.188443
    }, {
      lat: 39.074887,
      long: -120.187134
    }, {
      lat: 39.071210,
      long: -120.185336
    }, {
      lat: 39.067491,
      long: -120.183625
    }, {
      lat: 39.053039,
      long: -120.183695
    }, {
      lat: 39.038354,
      long: -120.183683
    },
  ],
  eastPlacer: [
    {
      lat: 39.373603,
      long: -120.216838
    }, {
      lat: 39.358984,
      long: -120.216856
    }, {
      lat: 39.344107,
      long: -120.216683
    }, {
      lat: 39.329376,
      long: -120.216833
    }, {
      lat: 39.315090,
      long: -120.217128
    }, {
      lat: 39.300554,
      long: -120.217113
    }, {
      lat: 39.285834,
      long: -120.217154
    }, {
      lat: 39.271439,
      long: -120.217729
    }, {
      lat: 39.256922,
      long: -120.217728
    }, {
      lat: 39.242498,
      long: -120.217577
    }, {
      lat: 39.227876,
      long: -120.217551
    }, {
      lat: 39.213208,
      long: -120.217543
    }, {
      lat: 39.198558,
      long: -120.217517
    }, {
      lat: 39.183976,
      long: -120.217368
    }, {
      lat: 39.183975,
      long: -120.217368
    }, {
      lat: 39.183805,
      long: -120.172043
    }, {
      lat: 39.168931,
      long: -120.171713
    }, {
      lat: 39.154654,
      long: -120.171681
    }, {
      lat: 39.154653,
      long: -120.171681
    }, {
      lat: 39.139767,
      long: -120.171765
    }, {
      lat: 39.125323,
      long: -120.171739
    }, {
      lat: 39.111128,
      long: -120.171530
    }, {
      lat: 39.096527,
      long: -120.171580
    }, {
      lat: 39.082052,
      long: -120.171833
    }, {
      lat: 39.080031,
      long: -120.170910
    }, {
      lat: 39.076672,
      long: -120.169374
    }, {
      lat: 39.072898,
      long: -120.167611
    }, {
      lat: 39.067501,
      long: -120.165205
    }, {
      lat: 39.053084,
      long: -120.164571
    }, {
      lat: 39.038447,
      long: -120.165066
    }
  ]
};

var loads = {
  westWashoe: [
    {
      elevation: 5000,
      snowload: 30
    }, {
      elevation: 5100,
      snowload: 41
    }, {
      elevation: 5200,
      snowload: 52
    }, {
      elevation: 5300,
      snowload: 64
    }, {
      elevation: 5400,
      snowload: 75
    }, {
      elevation: 5500,
      snowload: 86
    }, {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 142
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 171
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 200
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 215
    }, {
      elevation: 8000,
      snowload: 229
    }, {
      elevation: 8500,
      snowload: 243
    }, {
      elevation: 9000,
      snowload: 271
    }, {
      elevation: 9500,
      snowload: 300
    }, {
      elevation: 10000,
      snowload: 357
    }
  ],
  eastWashoe: [
    {
      elevation: 5000,
      snowload: 30
    }, {
      elevation: 5100,
      snowload: 31
    }, {
      elevation: 5200,
      snowload: 33
    }, {
      elevation: 5300,
      snowload: 34
    }, {
      elevation: 5400,
      snowload: 35
    }, {
      elevation: 5500,
      snowload: 37
    }, {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 43
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 43
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 57
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 57
    }, {
      elevation: 8000,
      snowload: 86
    }, {
      elevation: 8500,
      snowload: 86
    }, {
      elevation: 9000,
      snowload: 114
    }, {
      elevation: 9500,
      snowload: 142
    }
  ],
  basinWashoe: [
    {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 220
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 235
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 250
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 265
    }, {
      elevation: 8000,
      snowload: 280
    }, {
      elevation: 8500,
      snowload: 295
    }, {
      elevation: 9000,
      snowload: 330
    }, {
      elevation: 9500,
      snowload: 390
    }, {
      elevation: 10000,
      snowload: 420
    }
  ],
  westPlacer: [
    {
      elevation: 1000,
      snowload: 10,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 3.0
    }, {
      elevation: 1600,
      snowload: 20,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 3.0
    }, {
      elevation: 2500,
      snowload: 29,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 3.0
    }, {
      elevation: 3000,
      snowload: 55,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 3.0
    }, {
      elevation: 3500,
      snowload: 70,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 3.8
    }, {
      elevation: 4000,
      snowload: 100,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 5.0
    }, {
      elevation: 4500,
      snowload: 160,
      snowdensity: 22.7,
      snowdepth: 6.5
    }, {
      elevation: 5000,
      snowload: 200,
      snowdensity: 24.5,
      snowdepth: 8.2
    }, {
      elevation: 5500,
      snowload: 260,
      snowdensity: 26.7,
      snowdepth: 9.7
    }, {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 315,
      snowdensity: 27.0,
      snowdepth: 11.7
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 375,
      snowdensity: 29.6,
      snowdepth: 12.7
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 430,
      snowdensity: 30.1,
      snowdepth: 14.3
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 490,
      snowdensity: 30.6,
      snowdepth: 16.0
    }, {
      elevation: 7501,
      snowload: 545,
      snowdensity: 32.4,
      snowdepth: 16.8
    }
  ],
  eastPlacer: [
    {
      elevation: 5500,
      snowload: 130,
      snowdensity: 23.6,
      snowdepth: 5.5
    }, {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 190,
      snowdensity: 23.8,
      snowdepth: 7.9
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 245,
      snowdensity: 24.5,
      snowdepth: 10.0
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 300,
      snowdensity: 25.0,
      snowdepth: 12.0
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 360,
      snowdensity: 25.2,
      snowdepth: 14.3
    }, {
      elevation: 8000,
      snowload: 400,
      snowdensity: 25.5,
      snowdepth: 15.7
    }, {
      elevation: 8001,
      snowload: 445,
      snowdensity: 25.7,
      snowdepth: 17.3
    }
  ],
  westElDorado: [
    {
      elevation: 2000,
      snowload: 20
    }, {
      elevation: 2500,
      snowload: 32
    }, {
      elevation: 3000,
      snowload: 45
    }, {
      elevation: 3500,
      snowload: 56
    }, {
      elevation: 4000,
      snowload: 68
    }, {
      elevation: 4500,
      snowload: 80
    }, {
      elevation: 5000,
      snowload: 90
    }, {
      elevation: 5500,
      snowload: 100
    }, {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 110
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 120
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 128
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 135
    }
  ],
  basinElDorado: [
    {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 145
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 160
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 170
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 180
    }
  ]
};

var countyCalculations = {
  Washoe_County: function(latLng, elevation) {
    var eastInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("eastWashoe", elevation);
    var westInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("westWashoe", elevation);
    var basinInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("basinWashoe", elevation);

    return {
      county: "Washoe",
      snowload: "<br/>- if east of 395: " + round(eastInfo.snowload, 2) + " psf<br/>- if west of 395: " + round(westInfo.snowload, 2) + " psf<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowload, 2) + " psf",
      //snowdensity: "<br/>- if east of 395: " + round(eastInfo.snowdensity, 2) + " pcf<br/>- if west of 395: " + round(westInfo.snowdensity, 2) + " pcf<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowdensity, 2) + " pcf",
      //snowdepth: "<br/>- if east of 395: " + round(eastInfo.snowdepth, 2) + " feet<br/>- if west of 395: " + round(westInfo.snowdepth, 2) + " feet<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowdepth, 2) + " feet"
    };
  },

  Placer_County: function(latLng, elevation) {
    // get closest basin border reference points
    var eastReferencePoint = getNearestPointForRegionByLatitude("eastPlacer", latLng.lat());
    var westReferencePoint = getNearestPointForRegionByLatitude("westPlacer", latLng.lat());

    // is the longitude east of or in the basin
    var eastSnowInfo;
    if(latLng.lng() > westReferencePoint.long)
      eastSnowInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("eastPlacer", elevation);

    // is the longitude west of or in the basin
    var westSnowInfo;
    if(latLng.lng() < eastReferencePoint.long)
      westSnowInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("westPlacer", elevation);

    var snowload;
    var snowdensity;
    var snowdepth;

    // east AND not west snowloads calculated (longitude is east of the basin)
    if(eastSnowInfo && !westSnowInfo) {
      snowload = eastSnowInfo.snowload;
      snowdensity = eastSnowInfo.snowdensity;
      snowdepth = eastSnowInfo.snowdepth;
    }

    // west AND now east snowloads calculated (longitude is west of the basin)
    if(!eastSnowInfo && westSnowInfo) {
      snowload = westSnowInfo.snowload;
      snowdensity = westSnowInfo.snowdensity;
      snowdepth = westSnowInfo.snowdepth;
    }

    // were the east AND west snowloads calculated (longitude is in the basin)
    if(eastSnowInfo && westSnowInfo) {
      snowload = interpolate(latLng.lng(), westReferencePoint.long, eastReferencePoint.long, westSnowInfo.snowload, eastSnowInfo.snowload);
      snowdensity = interpolate(latLng.lng(), westReferencePoint.long, eastReferencePoint.long, westSnowInfo.snowdensity, eastSnowInfo.snowdensity);
      snowdepth = interpolate(latLng.lng(), westReferencePoint.long, eastReferencePoint.long, westSnowInfo.snowdepth, eastSnowInfo.snowdepth);
    }

    return {
      county: "Placer",
      snowload: round(snowload, 2) + " psf",
      snowdensity: round(snowdensity, 2) + " pcf",
      snowdepth: round(snowdepth, 2) + " feet"
    };
  },

  Nevada_County: function(latLng, elevation) {
    // Truckee uses Placer county algorithm
    var info = countyCalculations.Placer_County(latLng, elevation);
    info.county = "Nevada (Truckee only)";
    return info;
  },

  El_Dorado_County: function(latLng, elevation) {
    var westInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("westElDorado", elevation);
    var basinInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("basinElDorado", elevation);

    return {
      county: "El Dorado",
      snowload: "<br/>- if on West Slope: " + round(westInfo.snowload, 2) + " psf<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowload, 2) + " psf",
      //snowdensity: "<br/>- if on West Slope: " + round(westInfo.snowdensity, 2) + " pcf<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowdensity, 2) + " pcf",
      //snowdepth: "<br/>- if on West Slope: " + round(westInfo.snowdepth, 2) + " feet<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowdepth, 2) + " feet"
    };
  },

  Douglas_County: function(latLng, elevation) {
    return {
      county: "Douglas",
      snowload: (elevation <= 6000 ? 30 : 150) + " psf"
    };
  }
};

calculateSnowInfo = function(input, elevationOverride, success, error) {
  var geocoderService = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoderService.geocode(input, function(results, status) {
    if(status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
      error("Failed to translate address to coordinates via Google: " + status);
    else {
      var location = (input.latLng ? input.latLng : results[0].geometry.location);
      var formattedAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
      var county;
      var city;

      var result = results[0];
      for(componentIndex in result.address_components) {
        var component = result.address_components[componentIndex];
        for(typeIndex in component.types) {
          if(component.types[typeIndex] == "locality")
            city = component.long_name;
          if(component.types[typeIndex] == "administrative_area_level_2")
            county = component.long_name;
        }
      }

      var countyCalculate;
      if(!county) {
        error("Unable to determine county from address");
        return;
      }

      county = county.replace(" ", "_");

      if(countyCalculations[county]) {
        if(county == "Nevada" && city != "Truckee") {
          error("The address provided appears to be in Nevada county outside the limits of Truckee.  Only Truckee addresses are supported for this county.");
          return;
        }
        countyCalculate = countyCalculations[county];
      } else {
        error("The address provided appears to be in " + county + " county (only Placer, Washoe, Nevada, El Dorado, and Douglas counties are supported)");
        return;
      }

      if(elevationOverride) {
        var info = countyCalculate(location, elevationOverride);
        info.location = location;
        info.formattedAddress = formattedAddress;
        info.elevation = elevation + " feet (overriden)";
        success(info);
      } else {
        var elevationService = new google.maps.ElevationService();
        elevationService.getElevationForLocations({
          locations: [location]
        }, function(results, status) {
          if(status != google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK)
            error("Failed to get elevation data from Google: " + status);
          else {
            elevation = Math.round(results[0].elevation * 3.2808399);

            var info = countyCalculate(location, elevation);
            info.location = location;
            info.formattedAddress = formattedAddress;
            info.elevation = elevation + " feet";
            success(info);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

getNearestPointForRegionByLatitude = function(region, latitude) {
  var pointsRegion = points[region];

  var bestPoint;
  var bestDelta;

  for(pointIndex in pointsRegion) {
    point = pointsRegion[pointIndex];
    delta = Math.abs(point.lat - latitude);
    if(!bestPoint || delta < bestDelta) {
      bestDelta = delta;
      bestPoint = point;
    }
  }

  return bestPoint;
}

getSnowInfoForRegion = function(region, elevation) {
  var loadsRegion = loads[region];

  var lowerLoadInfo = loadsRegion[0];
  for(loadInfoIndex in loadsRegion) {
    loadInfo = loadsRegion[loadInfoIndex];
    if(loadInfo.elevation > elevation)
      break;
    lowerLoadInfo = loadInfo;
  }

  var upperLoadInfo = loadsRegion[loadsRegion.length - 1];
  for(loadInfoIndex in loadsRegion) {
    loadInfo = loadsRegion[loadInfoIndex];
    if(loadInfo.elevation >= elevation) {
      upperLoadInfo = loadInfo;
      break;
    }
  }

  var results = {};
  if(lowerLoadInfo.elevation == upperLoadInfo.elevation)
    return {
      snowload: lowerLoadInfo.snowload,
      snowdensity: lowerLoadInfo.snowdensity,
      snowdepth: lowerLoadInfo.snowdepth
    };
  else
    return {
      snowload: interpolate(elevation, lowerLoadInfo.elevation, upperLoadInfo.elevation, lowerLoadInfo.snowload, upperLoadInfo.snowload),
      snowdensity: interpolate(elevation, lowerLoadInfo.elevation, upperLoadInfo.elevation, lowerLoadInfo.snowdensity, upperLoadInfo.snowdensity),
      snowdepth: interpolate(elevation, lowerLoadInfo.elevation, upperLoadInfo.elevation, lowerLoadInfo.snowdepth, upperLoadInfo.snowdepth)
    };
}

interpolate = function(source, sourceLower, sourceUpper, targetLower, targetUpper) {
  return (((source - sourceLower) / (sourceUpper - sourceLower)) * (targetUpper - targetLower)) + targetLower;
}

round = function(number, places) {
  var offset = 10 * places;
  return Math.round(number * offset) / offset;
}
```

```css
/*
Title:      Zachary Engineering OVER_RIDE STYLES
Author:     matt@mattabron.com // Matt Abron: visualjelly.com 

.inside-page #wrapper #container .container_12 .main-content .grid_8.alpha .post_block .socshare .facebookdiv {
    float: right;
}
#map_canvas {
    float: left;
    height: 870px;
    width: 607px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
#map3d {
    float: left;
    height: 870px;
    width: 607px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.inside-page #wrapper #container .container_12 .main-content .grid_12.alpha.omega .project #snoload_wrap_v2 #snoload_form #address, #latitude, #longitude, #county, #latitude2, #longitude2, #county2, #elevation, #snowloadResult {
    float: right;
    width: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}
.inside-page #wrapper #container .container_12 .main-content .grid_12.alpha.omega .project #snoload_wrap_v2 #snoload_form button {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
.snoLoad_Label {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.snoLoad_Label_consec {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}
    
#snoLoadVersion {
    height: 160px;
    width: 216px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 126px;
    top: -545px;
    z-index: 50;
}
.SnoLoadCentered {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#wrapper #container .container_12 .main-content .grid_12.alpha.omega .project #snoload_wrap_v2 #map_canvas p {
    font-size: 10px;
}
#element.style {
    cursor: url("http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur"), default;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<title>ZACHARY ENGINEERING | Residential Engineering | Verion3</title>

<!-- CSS Start //-->

<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- JS Start //--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script> 
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBBiAQWE_6cpjMhaItS0N6Ew3KjHb6JOqg&sensor=true">
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/snowloadCalculator.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Functions - Main Js file --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.085304, -120.031185),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(clickEvent) {calculateByLocation(clickEvent.latLng);});
      }

      function calculateByAddress(address, elevationOverride) {
        calculateSnowInfo({address: address}, elevationOverride, successCallback, errorCallback);
      }

      function calculateByLocation(latLng, elevationOverride) {
        calculateSnowInfo({latLng: latLng}, elevationOverride, successCallback, errorCallback);
      }

      function successCallback(info) {
        var content = "Address: " + info.formattedAddress + "<br/>County: " + info.county + "<br/>Elevation: " + info.elevation + "<br/>Ground Snow Load: " + info.snowload + "<br/>";
        content += "Snow Density: " + (info.snowdensity ? info.snowdensity : "no data") + "<br/>";
        content += "Maximum Anticipated Snow Depth: " + (info.snowdensity ? info.snowdepth : "no data");
<!--Location: " + info.location + "<br/>-->
        
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.setPosition(info.location);
        
        infowindow.open(map);

        map.setCenter(info.location);
        map.setZoom(19);
        
        $("#address").val(info.formattedAddress);
        $("#addressElevation").val(info.elevation);
        $("#latitude").val(info.location.lat());
        $("#longitude").val(info.location.lng());
        $("#locationElevation").val(info.elevation);
      }

      function errorCallback(errorMessage) {alert(errorMessage);}
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
/*// Redirect if mobile device
    SA.redirection_mobile ({
      noredirection_param:"noredirection",
      mobile_url : "#", // If we develop a Zachary Mobile Site, We can lite up this to redirect
      mobile_prefix : "http",
      cookie_hours : "2" 
    });*/

$(window).load(function() {
    

    // load hidden map
    loadHiddenMap();
});

</script> 
<!-- JS End //--> 

<!-- Start Facebook Like Open Graph Tags -->
<meta property="og:title" content="Zachary Engineering" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://visualjelly.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="#" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Zachary Engineering" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="#" />
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-32880370-1']);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<body>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div id="snoload_wrap_v2">
              <div id="map_canvas"></div>
              <div id="snoload_form">
                <span class="snoLoad_Label">Address</span>
                <input id="address" type="text"/>
                <!--<span class="snoLoad_Label">Elevation (optional)</span>
                <input id="addressElevation" type="text"/><br/>-->
                <button onClick="calculateByAddress($('#address').val(), $('#addressElevation').val())">Calculate</button>
                <span class="snoLoad_Label">Latitude</span>
                <input id="latitude" type="text"/>
                <span class="snoLoad_Label">Longitude</span>
                <input id="longitude" type="text"/>
                <!--<span class="snoLoad_Label_consec">Elevation (optional)</span>
                <input id="locationElevation" type="text"/><br/>-->
                <button onClick="calculateByLocation(new google.maps.LatLng($('#latitude').val(), $('#longitude').val()), $('#locationElevation').val())">Calculate</button>
                <!--<span class="snoLoad_Label">Result</span> 
                <input id="snowloadResult" type="text"/>-->               
  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>       
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get a javascript error running the code snippet: `Uncaught ReferenceError: loadHiddenMap is not defined`, where is that function defined?  Is it needed?  Did you test the code snippet?  What is the error you get for El Dorado county?

Comment: BTW, this doesn't seem very **minimal**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that "El Dorado County" has two spaces in it, all the others only have one.

[String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) only replaces the first instance of a substring when called that way:

> **substr**
> A String that is to be replaced by newSubstr. It is treated as a literal string and is
> not interpreted as a regular expression. **Only the first occurrence will be replaced**

So this code:

```
  county = county.replace(" ", "_");
```

only replaces the first space, yielding "El_Dorado County", which doesn't match "El_Dorado_County".  Use a regex to replace all spaces:

> **regexp (pattern)**
> A RegExp object or literal. The match or matches are replaced with newSubstr or the value returned by the specified function.

Like this:

```
  const regex = /\s/gi;
  county = county.replace(regex, "_");
```

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**Working code snippet:**

```js
var points = {
  westPlacer: [
    {
      lat: 39.373490,
      long: -120.235205
    }, {
      lat: 39.359037,
      long: -120.235319
    }, {
      lat: 39.343940,
      long: -120.235506
    }, {
      lat: 39.329288,
      long: -120.235731
    }, {
      lat: 39.314982,
      long: -120.236251
    }, {
      lat: 39.300705,
      long: -120.236422
    }, {
      lat: 39.285794,
      long: -120.236672
    }, {
      lat: 39.271297,
      long: -120.236402
    }, {
      lat: 39.256740,
      long: -120.236290
    }, {
      lat: 39.242320,
      long: -120.236151
    }, {
      lat: 39.227314,
      long: -120.236011
    }, {
      lat: 39.213102,
      long: -120.235911
    }, {
      lat: 39.198786,
      long: -120.235766
    }, {
      lat: 39.184576,
      long: -120.236484
    }, {
      lat: 39.184575,
      long: -120.236484
    }, {
      lat: 39.184119,
      long: -120.228208
    }, {
      lat: 39.170143,
      long: -120.228036
    }, {
      lat: 39.154701,
      long: -120.190700
    }, {
      lat: 39.154700,
      long: -120.190700
    }, {
      lat: 39.140015,
      long: -120.190456
    }, {
      lat: 39.125517,
      long: -120.190547
    }, {
      lat: 39.111406,
      long: -120.190561
    }, {
      lat: 39.096556,
      long: -120.190558
    }, {
      lat: 39.082067,
      long: -120.190534
    }, {
      lat: 39.077698,
      long: -120.188443
    }, {
      lat: 39.074887,
      long: -120.187134
    }, {
      lat: 39.071210,
      long: -120.185336
    }, {
      lat: 39.067491,
      long: -120.183625
    }, {
      lat: 39.053039,
      long: -120.183695
    }, {
      lat: 39.038354,
      long: -120.183683
    },
  ],
  eastPlacer: [
    {
      lat: 39.373603,
      long: -120.216838
    }, {
      lat: 39.358984,
      long: -120.216856
    }, {
      lat: 39.344107,
      long: -120.216683
    }, {
      lat: 39.329376,
      long: -120.216833
    }, {
      lat: 39.315090,
      long: -120.217128
    }, {
      lat: 39.300554,
      long: -120.217113
    }, {
      lat: 39.285834,
      long: -120.217154
    }, {
      lat: 39.271439,
      long: -120.217729
    }, {
      lat: 39.256922,
      long: -120.217728
    }, {
      lat: 39.242498,
      long: -120.217577
    }, {
      lat: 39.227876,
      long: -120.217551
    }, {
      lat: 39.213208,
      long: -120.217543
    }, {
      lat: 39.198558,
      long: -120.217517
    }, {
      lat: 39.183976,
      long: -120.217368
    }, {
      lat: 39.183975,
      long: -120.217368
    }, {
      lat: 39.183805,
      long: -120.172043
    }, {
      lat: 39.168931,
      long: -120.171713
    }, {
      lat: 39.154654,
      long: -120.171681
    }, {
      lat: 39.154653,
      long: -120.171681
    }, {
      lat: 39.139767,
      long: -120.171765
    }, {
      lat: 39.125323,
      long: -120.171739
    }, {
      lat: 39.111128,
      long: -120.171530
    }, {
      lat: 39.096527,
      long: -120.171580
    }, {
      lat: 39.082052,
      long: -120.171833
    }, {
      lat: 39.080031,
      long: -120.170910
    }, {
      lat: 39.076672,
      long: -120.169374
    }, {
      lat: 39.072898,
      long: -120.167611
    }, {
      lat: 39.067501,
      long: -120.165205
    }, {
      lat: 39.053084,
      long: -120.164571
    }, {
      lat: 39.038447,
      long: -120.165066
    }
  ]
};

var loads = {
  westWashoe: [
    {
      elevation: 5000,
      snowload: 30
    }, {
      elevation: 5100,
      snowload: 41
    }, {
      elevation: 5200,
      snowload: 52
    }, {
      elevation: 5300,
      snowload: 64
    }, {
      elevation: 5400,
      snowload: 75
    }, {
      elevation: 5500,
      snowload: 86
    }, {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 142
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 171
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 200
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 215
    }, {
      elevation: 8000,
      snowload: 229
    }, {
      elevation: 8500,
      snowload: 243
    }, {
      elevation: 9000,
      snowload: 271
    }, {
      elevation: 9500,
      snowload: 300
    }, {
      elevation: 10000,
      snowload: 357
    }
  ],
  eastWashoe: [
    {
      elevation: 5000,
      snowload: 30
    }, {
      elevation: 5100,
      snowload: 31
    }, {
      elevation: 5200,
      snowload: 33
    }, {
      elevation: 5300,
      snowload: 34
    }, {
      elevation: 5400,
      snowload: 35
    }, {
      elevation: 5500,
      snowload: 37
    }, {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 43
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 43
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 57
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 57
    }, {
      elevation: 8000,
      snowload: 86
    }, {
      elevation: 8500,
      snowload: 86
    }, {
      elevation: 9000,
      snowload: 114
    }, {
      elevation: 9500,
      snowload: 142
    }
  ],
  basinWashoe: [
    {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 220
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 235
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 250
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 265
    }, {
      elevation: 8000,
      snowload: 280
    }, {
      elevation: 8500,
      snowload: 295
    }, {
      elevation: 9000,
      snowload: 330
    }, {
      elevation: 9500,
      snowload: 390
    }, {
      elevation: 10000,
      snowload: 420
    }
  ],
  westPlacer: [
    {
      elevation: 1000,
      snowload: 10,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 3.0
    }, {
      elevation: 1600,
      snowload: 20,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 3.0
    }, {
      elevation: 2500,
      snowload: 29,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 3.0
    }, {
      elevation: 3000,
      snowload: 55,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 3.0
    }, {
      elevation: 3500,
      snowload: 70,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 3.8
    }, {
      elevation: 4000,
      snowload: 100,
      snowdensity: 20,
      snowdepth: 5.0
    }, {
      elevation: 4500,
      snowload: 160,
      snowdensity: 22.7,
      snowdepth: 6.5
    }, {
      elevation: 5000,
      snowload: 200,
      snowdensity: 24.5,
      snowdepth: 8.2
    }, {
      elevation: 5500,
      snowload: 260,
      snowdensity: 26.7,
      snowdepth: 9.7
    }, {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 315,
      snowdensity: 27.0,
      snowdepth: 11.7
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 375,
      snowdensity: 29.6,
      snowdepth: 12.7
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 430,
      snowdensity: 30.1,
      snowdepth: 14.3
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 490,
      snowdensity: 30.6,
      snowdepth: 16.0
    }, {
      elevation: 7501,
      snowload: 545,
      snowdensity: 32.4,
      snowdepth: 16.8
    }
  ],
  eastPlacer: [
    {
      elevation: 5500,
      snowload: 130,
      snowdensity: 23.6,
      snowdepth: 5.5
    }, {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 190,
      snowdensity: 23.8,
      snowdepth: 7.9
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 245,
      snowdensity: 24.5,
      snowdepth: 10.0
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 300,
      snowdensity: 25.0,
      snowdepth: 12.0
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 360,
      snowdensity: 25.2,
      snowdepth: 14.3
    }, {
      elevation: 8000,
      snowload: 400,
      snowdensity: 25.5,
      snowdepth: 15.7
    }, {
      elevation: 8001,
      snowload: 445,
      snowdensity: 25.7,
      snowdepth: 17.3
    }
  ],
  westElDorado: [
    {
      elevation: 2000,
      snowload: 20
    }, {
      elevation: 2500,
      snowload: 32
    }, {
      elevation: 3000,
      snowload: 45
    }, {
      elevation: 3500,
      snowload: 56
    }, {
      elevation: 4000,
      snowload: 68
    }, {
      elevation: 4500,
      snowload: 80
    }, {
      elevation: 5000,
      snowload: 90
    }, {
      elevation: 5500,
      snowload: 100
    }, {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 110
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 120
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 128
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 135
    }
  ],
  basinElDorado: [
    {
      elevation: 6000,
      snowload: 145
    }, {
      elevation: 6500,
      snowload: 160
    }, {
      elevation: 7000,
      snowload: 170
    }, {
      elevation: 7500,
      snowload: 180
    }
  ]
};

var countyCalculations = {
  Washoe_County: function(latLng, elevation) {
    var eastInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("eastWashoe", elevation);
    var westInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("westWashoe", elevation);
    var basinInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("basinWashoe", elevation);

    return {
      county: "Washoe",
      snowload: "<br/>- if east of 395: " + round(eastInfo.snowload, 2) + " psf<br/>- if west of 395: " + round(westInfo.snowload, 2) + " psf<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowload, 2) + " psf",
      //snowdensity: "<br/>- if east of 395: " + round(eastInfo.snowdensity, 2) + " pcf<br/>- if west of 395: " + round(westInfo.snowdensity, 2) + " pcf<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowdensity, 2) + " pcf",
      //snowdepth: "<br/>- if east of 395: " + round(eastInfo.snowdepth, 2) + " feet<br/>- if west of 395: " + round(westInfo.snowdepth, 2) + " feet<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowdepth, 2) + " feet"
    };
  },

  Placer_County: function(latLng, elevation) {
    // get closest basin border reference points
    var eastReferencePoint = getNearestPointForRegionByLatitude("eastPlacer", latLng.lat());
    var westReferencePoint = getNearestPointForRegionByLatitude("westPlacer", latLng.lat());

    // is the longitude east of or in the basin
    var eastSnowInfo;
    if(latLng.lng() > westReferencePoint.long)
      eastSnowInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("eastPlacer", elevation);

    // is the longitude west of or in the basin
    var westSnowInfo;
    if(latLng.lng() < eastReferencePoint.long)
      westSnowInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("westPlacer", elevation);

    var snowload;
    var snowdensity;
    var snowdepth;

    // east AND not west snowloads calculated (longitude is east of the basin)
    if(eastSnowInfo && !westSnowInfo) {
      snowload = eastSnowInfo.snowload;
      snowdensity = eastSnowInfo.snowdensity;
      snowdepth = eastSnowInfo.snowdepth;
    }

    // west AND now east snowloads calculated (longitude is west of the basin)
    if(!eastSnowInfo && westSnowInfo) {
      snowload = westSnowInfo.snowload;
      snowdensity = westSnowInfo.snowdensity;
      snowdepth = westSnowInfo.snowdepth;
    }

    // were the east AND west snowloads calculated (longitude is in the basin)
    if(eastSnowInfo && westSnowInfo) {
      snowload = interpolate(latLng.lng(), westReferencePoint.long, eastReferencePoint.long, westSnowInfo.snowload, eastSnowInfo.snowload);
      snowdensity = interpolate(latLng.lng(), westReferencePoint.long, eastReferencePoint.long, westSnowInfo.snowdensity, eastSnowInfo.snowdensity);
      snowdepth = interpolate(latLng.lng(), westReferencePoint.long, eastReferencePoint.long, westSnowInfo.snowdepth, eastSnowInfo.snowdepth);
    }

    return {
      county: "Placer",
      snowload: round(snowload, 2) + " psf",
      snowdensity: round(snowdensity, 2) + " pcf",
      snowdepth: round(snowdepth, 2) + " feet"
    };
  },

  Nevada_County: function(latLng, elevation) {
    // Truckee uses Placer county algorithm
    var info = countyCalculations.Placer_County(latLng, elevation);
    info.county = "Nevada (Truckee only)";
    return info;
  },

  El_Dorado_County: function(latLng, elevation) {
    var westInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("westElDorado", elevation);
    var basinInfo = getSnowInfoForRegion("basinElDorado", elevation);

    return {
      county: "El Dorado",
      snowload: "<br/>- if on West Slope: " + round(westInfo.snowload, 2) + " psf<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowload, 2) + " psf",
      //snowdensity: "<br/>- if on West Slope: " + round(westInfo.snowdensity, 2) + " pcf<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowdensity, 2) + " pcf",
      //snowdepth: "<br/>- if on West Slope: " + round(westInfo.snowdepth, 2) + " feet<br/>- if in Tahoe Basin: " + round(basinInfo.snowdepth, 2) + " feet"
    };
  },

  Douglas_County: function(latLng, elevation) {
    return {
      county: "Douglas",
      snowload: (elevation <= 6000 ? 30 : 150) + " psf"
    };
  }
};

calculateSnowInfo = function(input, elevationOverride, success, error) {
  var geocoderService = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoderService.geocode(input, function(results, status) {
    if(status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
      error("Failed to translate address to coordinates via Google: " + status);
    else {
      var location = (input.latLng ? input.latLng : results[0].geometry.location);
      var formattedAddress = results[0].formatted_address;
      var county;
      var city;

      var result = results[0];
      for(componentIndex in result.address_components) {
        var component = result.address_components[componentIndex];
        for(typeIndex in component.types) {
          if(component.types[typeIndex] == "locality")
            city = component.long_name;
          if(component.types[typeIndex] == "administrative_area_level_2")
            county = component.long_name;
        }
      }

      var countyCalculate;
      if(!county) {
        error("Unable to determine county from address");
        return;
      }

      const regex = /\s/gi;
      county = county.replace(regex, "_");

      if(countyCalculations[county]) {
        if(county == "Nevada" && city != "Truckee") {
          error("The address provided appears to be in Nevada county outside the limits of Truckee.  Only Truckee addresses are supported for this county.");
          return;
        }
        countyCalculate = countyCalculations[county];
      } else {
        error("The address provided appears to be in " + county + " county (only Placer, Washoe, Nevada, El Dorado, and Douglas counties are supported)");
        return;
      }

      if(elevationOverride) {
        var info = countyCalculate(location, elevationOverride);
        info.location = location;
        info.formattedAddress = formattedAddress;
        info.elevation = elevation + " feet (overriden)";
        success(info);
      } else {
        var elevationService = new google.maps.ElevationService();
        elevationService.getElevationForLocations({
          locations: [location]
        }, function(results, status) {
          if(status != google.maps.ElevationStatus.OK)
            error("Failed to get elevation data from Google: " + status);
          else {
            elevation = Math.round(results[0].elevation * 3.2808399);

            var info = countyCalculate(location, elevation);
            info.location = location;
            info.formattedAddress = formattedAddress;
            info.elevation = elevation + " feet";
            success(info);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

getNearestPointForRegionByLatitude = function(region, latitude) {
  var pointsRegion = points[region];

  var bestPoint;
  var bestDelta;

  for(pointIndex in pointsRegion) {
    point = pointsRegion[pointIndex];
    delta = Math.abs(point.lat - latitude);
    if(!bestPoint || delta < bestDelta) {
      bestDelta = delta;
      bestPoint = point;
    }
  }

  return bestPoint;
}

getSnowInfoForRegion = function(region, elevation) {
  var loadsRegion = loads[region];

  var lowerLoadInfo = loadsRegion[0];
  for(loadInfoIndex in loadsRegion) {
    loadInfo = loadsRegion[loadInfoIndex];
    if(loadInfo.elevation > elevation)
      break;
    lowerLoadInfo = loadInfo;
  }

  var upperLoadInfo = loadsRegion[loadsRegion.length - 1];
  for(loadInfoIndex in loadsRegion) {
    loadInfo = loadsRegion[loadInfoIndex];
    if(loadInfo.elevation >= elevation) {
      upperLoadInfo = loadInfo;
      break;
    }
  }

  var results = {};
  if(lowerLoadInfo.elevation == upperLoadInfo.elevation)
    return {
      snowload: lowerLoadInfo.snowload,
      snowdensity: lowerLoadInfo.snowdensity,
      snowdepth: lowerLoadInfo.snowdepth
    };
  else
    return {
      snowload: interpolate(elevation, lowerLoadInfo.elevation, upperLoadInfo.elevation, lowerLoadInfo.snowload, upperLoadInfo.snowload),
      snowdensity: interpolate(elevation, lowerLoadInfo.elevation, upperLoadInfo.elevation, lowerLoadInfo.snowdensity, upperLoadInfo.snowdensity),
      snowdepth: interpolate(elevation, lowerLoadInfo.elevation, upperLoadInfo.elevation, lowerLoadInfo.snowdepth, upperLoadInfo.snowdepth)
    };
}

interpolate = function(source, sourceLower, sourceUpper, targetLower, targetUpper) {
  return (((source - sourceLower) / (sourceUpper - sourceLower)) * (targetUpper - targetLower)) + targetLower;
}

round = function(number, places) {
  var offset = 10 * places;
  return Math.round(number * offset) / offset;
}
```

```css
/*
Title:      Zachary Engineering OVER_RIDE STYLES
Author:     matt@mattabron.com // Matt Abron: visualjelly.com 
*/
.inside-page #wrapper #container .container_12 .main-content .grid_8.alpha .post_block .socshare .facebookdiv {
    float: right;
}
#map_canvas {
    float: left;
    height: 870px;
    width: 607px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
#map3d {
    float: left;
    height: 870px;
    width: 607px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
.inside-page #wrapper #container .container_12 .main-content .grid_12.alpha.omega .project #snoload_wrap_v2 #snoload_form #address, #latitude, #longitude, #county, #latitude2, #longitude2, #county2, #elevation, #snowloadResult {
    float: right;
    width: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 9px;
}
.inside-page #wrapper #container .container_12 .main-content .grid_12.alpha.omega .project #snoload_wrap_v2 #snoload_form button {
    margin-left: 10px;
    width: 200px;
}
.snoLoad_Label {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 7px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}
.snoLoad_Label_consec {
    float: left;
    padding-top: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
}
    
#snoLoadVersion {
    height: 160px;
    width: 216px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 126px;
    top: -545px;
    z-index: 50;
}
.SnoLoadCentered {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
#wrapper #container .container_12 .main-content .grid_12.alpha.omega .project #snoload_wrap_v2 #map_canvas p {
    font-size: 10px;
}
#element.style {
    cursor: url("http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/openhand_8_8.cur"), default;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />
<meta name="keywords" content="" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<title>ZACHARY ENGINEERING | Residential Engineering | Verion3</title>

<!-- CSS Start //-->

<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- JS Start //--> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $ = jQuery.noConflict();
</script> 
    
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBBiAQWE_6cpjMhaItS0N6Ew3KjHb6JOqg">
</script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/snowloadCalculator.js"></script>
<!-- Custom Functions - Main Js file --> 
<script type="text/javascript">
      var map;
      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      function initialize() {
        var myOptions = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.085304, -120.031185),
          zoom: 11,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(clickEvent) {calculateByLocation(clickEvent.latLng);});
      }

      function calculateByAddress(address, elevationOverride) {
        calculateSnowInfo({address: address}, elevationOverride, successCallback, errorCallback);
      }

      function calculateByLocation(latLng, elevationOverride) {
        calculateSnowInfo({latLng: latLng}, elevationOverride, successCallback, errorCallback);
      }

      function successCallback(info) {
        var content = "Address: " + info.formattedAddress + "<br/>County: " + info.county + "<br/>Elevation: " + info.elevation + "<br/>Ground Snow Load: " + info.snowload + "<br/>";
        content += "Snow Density: " + (info.snowdensity ? info.snowdensity : "no data") + "<br/>";
        content += "Maximum Anticipated Snow Depth: " + (info.snowdensity ? info.snowdepth : "no data");
<!--Location: " + info.location + "<br/>-->
        
        infowindow.setContent(content);
        infowindow.setPosition(info.location);
        
        infowindow.open(map);

        map.setCenter(info.location);
        map.setZoom(19);
        
        $("#address").val(info.formattedAddress);
        $("#addressElevation").val(info.elevation);
        $("#latitude").val(info.location.lat());
        $("#longitude").val(info.location.lng());
        $("#locationElevation").val(info.elevation);
      }

      function errorCallback(errorMessage) {alert(errorMessage);}
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
/*// Redirect if mobile device
    SA.redirection_mobile ({
      noredirection_param:"noredirection",
      mobile_url : "#", // If we develop a Zachary Mobile Site, We can lite up this to redirect
      mobile_prefix : "http",
      cookie_hours : "2" 
    });*/

$(window).load(function() {
    

    // load hidden map
    initialize();
});

</script> 
<!-- JS End //--> 
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
<body>
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div id="snoload_wrap_v2">
              <div id="map_canvas"></div>
              <div id="snoload_form">
                <span class="snoLoad_Label">Address</span>
                <input id="address" type="text"/>
                <!--<span class="snoLoad_Label">Elevation (optional)</span>
                <input id="addressElevation" type="text"/><br/>-->
                <button onClick="calculateByAddress($('#address').val(), $('#addressElevation').val())">Calculate</button>
                <span class="snoLoad_Label">Latitude</span>
                <input id="latitude" type="text"/>
                <span class="snoLoad_Label">Longitude</span>
                <input id="longitude" type="text"/>
                <!--<span class="snoLoad_Label_consec">Elevation (optional)</span>
                <input id="locationElevation" type="text"/><br/>-->
                <button onClick="calculateByLocation(new google.maps.LatLng($('#latitude').val(), $('#longitude').val()), $('#locationElevation').val())">Calculate</button>
                <!--<span class="snoLoad_Label">Result</span> 
                <input id="snowloadResult" type="text"/>-->               
  
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>       
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```